# Login loop with ANY Nvidia graphics driver (16.04, 14.04, 17.04)

Tags: 16.04, drivers, nvidia, graphics, login

Before this gets marked as duplicate I want to say I have read through countless threads([like this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760934/graphics-issues-after-while-installing-ubuntu-16-04-16-10-with-nvidia-graphics)) regarding a login loop caused by nvidia graphics drivers.
I have attempted every solution listed, reinstalled ubuntu many times, and even tried other versions. I am currently on 16.04 but I have tried 14.04 and 17.04 as well. I am quite new to ubuntu and very lost. My goal is to be able to play games using my gtx 960m graphics card.
I wasn't really sure what information to include in my post so feel free to ask any questions about my laptop or anything else.
Thanks so much!